# 'TypeError: store.dispatch is not a function' redux action testing with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I'm trying to write a test for this redux action:

`export const clearError = () => (dispatch: Dispatch<IStoreState>) => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CLEAR_ACTIVATION_ERRORS });`

Don't understand why it's happened because I did everything from the example step by step. This is my test:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import * as actionTypes from '@const/actions';

import './__mocks__/reactNativeConfig';

import * as actions from '../index';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('index.ts -> clearError', async () => {
  it('clearError', () => {
    const expectedAction = {
      type: actionTypes.CLEAR_ACTIVATION_ERRORS,
    };

    const store = mockStore;

    return store.dispatch(actions.clearError)
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
      }
    );
  });
});
```

and when I run my test I have an error:

```
      18 |     const store = mockStore;
      19 | 
    > 20 |     return store.dispatch(actions.clearError)
         |                  ^
      21 |       .then(() => {
      22 |         expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
      23 |       }
```

Please, colud you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Testing should be unit testing. You don't need to dispatch real action. Just test your reducer whether it is doing the required state change or not.

Answer (score 0):

try giving mock store data like the example below

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import * as actionTypes from '@const/actions';

import './__mocks__/reactNativeConfig';

import * as actions from '../index';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('index.ts -> clearError', async () => {
  it('clearError', () => {
    const expectedAction = {
      type: actionTypes.CLEAR_ACTIVATION_ERRORS,
    };

    const store = mockStore("mock store data should be given here({loading: false})");

    return store.dispatch(actions.clearError)
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
      }
    );
  });
});
```